# Updating input value by updating props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a input value which I fail to update after clicking on Reset link

```
class DiscountEditor extends Component {
    render() {
        <div className="inline field">
            <a className="ui reset" onClick={this.props.onReset}>Reset</a>

            <input
                value={this.props.discount}
                onChange={this.props.onDiscountChanged}>
            </input>
        </div>
   }
}

class SalesLine extends Component {
    onReset(lineItem) {
        this._discount = 0;
        this.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        <DiscountEditor
            value={this._discount}
            onChange={this.props.onDiscountChanged}
            onReset={this.onReset.bind(this)}
        </DiscountEditor>
    }
}
```

as I click on reset button DiscountEditor  component will be rendered again and the this.props.discount has the correct value which is zero but the input value will remain the same and won't get updated to zero. 
Why though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called the prop `value` but you are using `this.props.discount`. If you change it to

```
<input
    value={this.props.value}
    onChange={this.props.onDiscountChanged}>
</input>
```

it should work.

You should also put `discount` into state in your `SalesLine` component instead of calling `forceUpdate` manually.

```
class SalesLine extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {discount: 0};
   }

   onReset(lineItem) {
      this.setState({discount: 0});
   }

   render() {
     return <DiscountEditor
       value={this.state.discount}
       onChange={this.props.onDiscountChanged}
       onReset={this.onReset.bind(this)}
     </DiscountEditor>;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign _discount to your state in the constructor and from there on update the state

```
class SalesLine extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {discount: this.props.discount};
   }

   onReset(lineItem) {
      this.setState({discount: 0});
   }

   render() {
     return <DiscountEditor
       value={this.state.discount}
       onChange={this.props.onDiscountChanged}
       onReset={this.onReset.bind(this)}
     </DiscountEditor>;
   }
}
```